# Systematic use of incomplete gamma function

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals, gamma-function

> Prove that
>   $$\int_0^r\frac{2x}{r^2}\exp\left({-\frac{πvx^\frac{2d}{c}}{t^{\frac2c}}}\right) \,\mathrm dx=\frac cd\frac{t^{\frac2d}}{r^2}\left(\frac1{πv}\right)^{\frac cd}γ\left(\frac cd,\ πv\left(\frac{r^d}t\right)^{\frac2c}\right).$$ 
>   Hint: on changing variables $$y=\frac{πvx^{\frac{2d}{c}}}{t^{\frac{2}{c}}}.$$

Note: $$ \gamma \left ( a,b \right )=\int_{0}^{b}x^{a-1}e^{-x} \,\mathrm{d}x$$ is the incomplete gamma function.

I am asking here as I have not been able to get through with its step-by-step proof. However I have verified the answer is correct using [integral calculator](https://www.integral-calculator.com/)

Comment: Please provide context for the question and what exactly you have tried so far in order to get positive response from the community.

Comment: Your edit changed the context of the question. I have made the corrections

Answer (score 3):

(Mis)using this integral calculator was a bad idea.

Your integral can be written as

$$2pq\int xe^{-px^2}dx=-qe^{-px^2}+C.$$

Comment: @Abdulhameed: details ? What details ? This is an obvious antiderivative. Substitute $t=x^2$.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I think the details are necessary. For instance both $t$ and $x$ are variables in the question! Also, would like to know where I can refer to for the above relation. Making $p = \frac{1}{r^{2}}$ also does not seem to work.

Comment: @Abdulhameed No, only $x$ is a variable. The rest is basic arithmetic, nothing to do with integrals.

Comment: I mean why do we use $ t = x ^{2} $ when $t$ and $x$ are both within the framework of the question. Pardon my questions please, I seem not to get this "basic arithmetic"

Comment: Mh, I see. Read "substitute $y=x^2$".

Comment: I haven't gotten it still please could I see your worked version? Thank you

Comment: @Abdulhameed: done mentally.

Comment: Please, at your convenience, I will appreciate it in full. Thanks

Comment: @Abdulhameed: I mean it. It is so simple that it is done mentally. No intermediate steps.